# Open txt file and insert it's content into table accordingly

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I want to read contents of a text file and insert the contents into a table
This is the content of the text file

```
--------------------------------
Text file contents
--------------------------------
[playlist]
mode=play
Title1=Radio 1|United Kingdom                                                              
File1=http://www.test.com/0001                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
Title2=Radio 2 |United States                                                                        
File2=http://www.test.com/0002                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
Title3=Radio 3|United Kingdom                                                                          
File3=http://www.test.com/0003                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        
NumberOfEntries=3
Version=2
-------------------------------
```

And store in a table like this

```
  id  |     item                |   url
----------------------------------------------------------
  1   | Radio 1|United Kingdom  | http://www.test.com/0001 
  2   | Radio 2 |United States  | http://www.test.com/0002 
  3   | Radio 3|United Kingdom  | http://www.test.com/0003
```

How do i grab Title and File so that I can insert it into a DB table.
I am using file_get_contents() to read text file.

My current code:

```
$content = file_get_contents("textfile.txt");

$lines = explode("\n", $content);

foreach ($lines as $line) {
    $row = explode("", $line);


    $stmt="INSERT INTO table_1 (item, url)
    VALUES
    (....)";

}
```

Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: you will need to extract the title and file using preg_match_all instead of explode.

Comment: you should read about regular expressions, and do it that way

Comment: how how do i do that please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the file is always the same format you can parse the data and build an array

```
$content = file_get_contents('textfile.txt');
$lines = explode("\n", $content);
$data = array();
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    if (preg_match('/^(Title|File)([0-9]+)\=(.+)$/', $line, $match)) {
        $data[$match[2]][$match[1]] = $match[3];
    }
}
```

After that you can loop trough the data array and insert into the database.

```
foreach($data as $id => $values) {
    $sql = 'INSERT INTO table_1 (item, url) VALUES ("' .    $values['Title'] . '", "'  . $values['File'] . '")';//The values need to be escaped!
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much I'll have a go using your method

Comment: it gave me gibberish data  :( OUTPUT => mRhUhUhUhUhUhUhUhPhPhPhRhWhMhShWhChShIhLhBhRhChFh2hThRhNhShRhShRhShShRhWhGhThWhAhRhPhFhRhGhNhPhihLhIh52

Comment: That does not make any sense at all, could you edit your post and add the output of `var_dump($lines);` after `$content = file_get_contents("textfile.txt");$lines = explode("\n", $content);`

Comment: Thank you for getting back to me var_dump($lines) gave me correct contents but now the page goes blank, data is not inserted on DB table and no errors showing at all. Sorry for being a noob :(

Comment: Could you post the output of the var_dump?, could you also post the var_dump of $data after the first part of my code?

Comment: The var_dump($lines) is like this: array(10) { [0]=> string(14) "ï»¿[playlist] " [1]=> string(10) "mode=play " [2]=> string(92) "Title1=Radio 1|United Kingdom " [3]=> string(1000) "File1=http://www.test.com/0001 " [4]=> string(102) "Title2=Radio 2 |United States " [5]=> string(999) "File2=http://www.test.com/0002 " [6]=> string(104) "Title3=Radio 3|United Kingdom " [7]=> string(999) "File3=http://www.test.com/0003 " [8]=> string(18) "NumberOfEntries=3 " [9]=> string(9) "Version=2" }

Comment: It worked finally!! I was just being silly Thanks everybody specially @Bart Haalstra